# Change highlighted text of comment

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I deleted the text my MSWord comment refers to. Now there is only a vertical bar, at the start of one of my sentences, that is connected to the comment with a dotted line.

What is the easiest way to change the 'begin' and 'end' position of the MSWord text that is referred to by a particular comment?

So that a sentence that already appears in my Word doc, now obtains the 'comment highlighting' to show it is connected to this particular comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to change the 'begin' and 'end' position of the MSWord text that is referred to by a particular comment?

The only way I know to do this is to drag text into or out of the commented region.  Yes, it's clumsy, but it's Microsoft.

> I deleted the text my MSWord comment refers to.  Now there is only a vertical bar, at the start of one of my sentences, which is connected to the comment with a dotted line.

AFAIK, you're stuck with copying the comment text, deleting the comment, and recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

Another less-than-ideal way is to copy the text of the comment, delete the comment, select new area of text, insert a comment, and paste into it the previous text.